# Debugging Fortran mixed with C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, c++-cli, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a solution (VS 2015) with a Fortran console application-project (Intel Fortran compiler) and a C++/CLI library. I'm calling into the C++ library via Fortran C-bindings.

Example function on the C++-side:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PrintInteger(const int * const a)
{
  std::cout << *a << std::endl;
}
```

Corresponding function on the Fortran side:

```
module CplusplusWrapper
  interface
    subroutine PrintInteger(a) bind (C, name = "PrintInteger" )
      use iso_c_binding
      implicit none
      integer (c_int), intent(in) :: a
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module
```

Now, fortunately, I got this to work. And I can even start debugging the Fortran application and then step into the called C++ code. However, as soon as I add any managed functionality to my C++/CLI project, this doesn't work any more. It doesn't even have to be in the same function, it can be a totally different file...

I already tried going to the C++-project's properties -> Configuration -> Debugging and set the debugger type to "mixed", to no effect.

Any hints on how to enable debugging into managed code?

Comment: The debugger type must be Mixed.  And you need Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Use Managed Compatibility Mode ticked on VS versions >= VS2012.  And you need a breakpoint on the C++/CLI code, you cannot single-step from native code into managed code.

Comment: Both options are now set as you said, but the Debugger does not reach the breakpoints. If I try to single step into the C++/CLI-code, it tells me "Source not available". However, the *.pdb file for the c++ project is in the same directory as the fortran-executable. Any more ideas? :-)

Comment: Debug > Windows > Modules, ensure that the DLL you want to debug is in the list.  Right-click it  > Symbol Load Information tells you where it looked for the PDB file.  If the debugger cannot locate source then it will prompt you for the location.  If you ever clicked Cancel then it is not going to ask you again.  Right-click the Solution node > Properties > Debug Source Files > "Do not look" list should be empty.  You can add a directory in the same dialog.

Comment: In the modules window (only accessible while debugging, took me some time to find that out), it tells me that the symbols for my c++ dll were loaded, which is also mentioned in the debug log... Weird...

Comment: Any more ideas? I verified that the possibility to debug actually vanishes as soon as I change the C++ project from unmanaged to /CLR, even if I do not introduce anything "managed". I also tried a bunch of other switches, to no success...

Comment: @Timitry, Ensure you have "enable native debugging" selected in the project properties (debug section) for the C++ project, and then debug it again in debug mode. how about the result?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT The option "Debugger type" is set to "Mixed" (that's what you meant, right?), and I'm debugging in debug-mode. I already tried setting it to different values, to no effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, which is described on the [intel website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-debug-a-fortran-application-calling-a-managed-dll).

Create a dummy C# class library, which does not need to contain any files. Set this dummy project as start project of  your solution (right click -> set as start project).

On the new project's options page under "Debug", set "Start Action" from "Start project" to "Start external program", and select your fortran-executable there. Further down, check the option "Enable native code debugging".

To get the correct build order within Visual Studio, right-click you project, choose "Build dependencies" -> "Project dependencies" and there checkmark your fortran application. This ensures that the fortran application will be build first if outdated when you hit "Start debugging".

It may well be possible to use any other kind of managed project (VB.NET, C++/CLI, ...) as dummy project, however, I haven't tested that since my solution contains C# projects anyway.